# Is the Avatar of the Vengeful Monkey mathematically worth it when dealing with late game B.A.D.s?

Tags: bloons-td-6

When getting to the late rounds (200+), is it worth it to use the Avatar of the Vengeful Monkey? Or instead, is it worth it to have all three of the Tier 5 Super Monkeys?

This is in regards to dealing damage to the power scaled fortified B.A.D.s and other M.O.A.B. class bloons that you come across in the extremely late rounds, and which of the sets (Vengeful or 3 Tier 5) would end up dealing more damage to them.

Comment: Maybe if you define "worth it" this question can remain open. Right now, it's hard to interpret your question, hence it's being closed.

Comment: @Joachim I don't understand how it is opinion based, as the answer would be if the mathematical damage output of the tower is worth it in the late game compared to the potential output of the 3 other tier 5 super monkeys. I went and clarified what I was looking for regardless.

Comment: Given how Bloons gameplay works, seeing if a high-cost monkey is worth using or not is fairly understandable when comparing it to other options for the cost.

Comment: Yes, but that is a (logical but still an) interpretation of "worth it", and should be explicated in your question.